# boost interprocess error in boost interprocess containers

Tags: c++, boost, interprocess, boost-interprocess

I am having a boost interprocess vector which contains string (boost::interprocess::basic_string) as values kept in shared memory, I am getting this error in long run

> `include/boost/interprocess/mem_algo/rbtree_best_fit.hpp:1346: void boost::interprocess::rbtree_best_fit<MutexFamily, VoidMutex, MemAlignment>::priv_deallocate(void*) [with MutexFamily = boost::interprocess::mutex_family; VoidPointer = boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<void>; long unsigned int MemAlignment = 0ul]: Assertion`priv_is_allocated_block(block)' failed.`

There is total 6 process writing to this vector and one process popping the data out.

Questions:

1. Is there any limitation in number of process accessing a shared memory, especially boost managed containers.
2. What I understand is that the segment manager and mem algorithm is kept in the shared memory itself, Is it correct?

I use this class:

```
class SharedVector {
public:
    boost::interprocess::interprocess_mutex mutex;
    complex_vect_type m_vect;
    SharedVector(const void_allocator &a) : m_vect(a) {}
};
```

and for creation am doing this:

```
memsegment->construct<SharedVector>("sharedvector") (*m_allocator);
```

and in the other process am doing this to access it

```
mem_segment->find<SharedVector>(t"sharedvector").first;
```

Comment: `class SharedVector
{
 public: 
   boost::interprocess::interprocess_mutex mutex; 
   complex_vect_type m_vect;
   SharedVector(const void_allocator &a) : m_vect(a) { }
 } `
 and for creation am doing this : 
`memsegment->construct<SharedVector>("sharedvector") (*m_allocator);`
 and in the other process am doing this to access it 
`mem_segment->find<SharedVector>(t"sharedvector").first; `

Answer (score 0):

1. No there is no limitation
2. yes

You don't mention any locking. I guess this explains your problems.

Multiple processes access shared resources *concurrently* require the same amount of synchronization of access as multiple threads. Difference being, of course, that you use interprocess synchronization objects

Comment: Thanks, I have a boost interprocess murex lock, and am locking in push and pop operation. But still in the slave process I get the error specified in the question, please help

Comment: Do you check for `empty()` before `pop()`? Do you hold the lock across `empty()` and `pop()`? (And: please don't **"please help"** on SO. It's disrespectful. It's blindingly obvious we're here to help).

Comment: Thanks, I do check size() > 0 before pop and also have a lock before that , i have written a function for pop , which locks then checks the size and then pops the data out.

Comment: @LasyaLatha time to show the code then. Make it a SSCCE. We're not psychics.

Comment: This is the object which i keep in shared memory :
`class SharedVector
{
public:
   boost::interprocess::interprocess_mutex mutex;
    complex_vect_type m_vect;
 SharedVector(const void_allocator &a) : m_vect(a) {
        }
}`

and for creation am doing this :

`memsegment->construct<SharedVector>("sharedvector") (*m_allocator);`

and in the other process am doing this to access it
`mem_segment->find<SharedVector>(t"sharedvector").first;`

Comment: `inline void pop()
{
  boost::interprocess::scoped_lock< boost::interprocess::interprocess_mutex> lock(sharedobj->mutex);
if(sharedobj->m_vect.size() > 0)
sharedobj->m_vect.pop();

}`

}

Comment: @LasyaLatha, post **Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example**, see [this](http://sscce.org/) for details. You can edit your post and add it there instead of trying to squeeze any longer code in comments which is hard to read.